# URL is inheriting the wrong get variables despite being specified correctly

Tags: php, get

The web form I built for my client has been working fine for weeks, however recently he told me he wanted me to introduce a 4th control to the form to further refine results.
The problem I am having is that my url keeps rendering incorrectly which messes up the query I run later on my page.

Old URL

```
http://mysite.com/product?s=INTERMITTENT&p=1300&g=1200
```

The above URL searches all products with the id of intermittent and then filters on their total throughputs p&g, this worked fine until he wanted me to introduce the 4th control which would allow conversions between metric and imperial, the new URL looks somewhat like this

```
http://mysite.com/product?s=INTERMITTENT&m=IMPERIAL&p=1000&g=350
```

However, each time the form submits I am presented with something along the lines of

```
http://mysite.com/product?s=IMPERIAL&m=IMPERIAL&p=1000&g=350
```

I cannot for the life of me fathom why the output is behaving this way

HTML Markup

```
<form id="pumpSlider" action="" method="GET" align="center">
    <input id="bS" type="hidden" name="s" value="<?php echo $pType ?>" />
       <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
         <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'INTERMITTENT' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but1">INTERMITTENT</button>
         <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'CONTINUOUS' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but4">CONTINUOUS</button>  
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" name="m" value="<?php echo $_GET['m'] ?>" />
         <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" style="display:block; padding-top: 20px;">
           <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $_GET['m'] == 'METRIC' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but5">METRIC</button>
           <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $_GET['m'] == 'IMPERIAL' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but6">IMPERIAL</button> 
         </div>                

     <div align="center" class="productSlider">
        <p class="inlineLabel">PSI</p><div class="filterSlider" id="psiSlider"></div>
        <p class="inlineLabel">GPM</p><div class="filterSlider" id="gpmSlider"></div>

        <input id="pS" type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $pVal ?> " />
        <input id="gS" type="hidden" name="g" value="<?php echo $gVal ?>" />
     </div>
 </form>
```

The hidden inputs take on the value of the submit field which they are attributed to

I guess the problem may lie in my PHP code, but I do not see where

```
# Check if each variable is set, if not delegate default values.
if(!isset($_GET['m']) || !isset($_GET['p']) || !isset($_GET['g']) || !isset($_GET['s'])){
    $_GET['m'] = "IMPERIAL";
    $_GET['g'] = "0";
    $_GET['p'] = "0";
    $_GET['s'] = "INTERMITTENT";
    $cVal = "classic";
}

# Validate the input is correct (check for tampered URL)
if(isset($_GET['s'])){
  if(preg_match('/^[INTERMITTENT | CONTINUOUS ]+$/', stripslashes(trim($_GET['s']))))
  {
    $pType = $_GET['s'];
    $cVal = "classic";
  } else {
    $pType = "INTERMITTENT";
    $cVal = "classic";
  }
}   

if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    if(preg_match('%^[0-9]{1,6}$%', stripslashes(trim($_GET['p']))))
    {
        $pVal = $_GET['p'];
    } else {
        $pVal = "0";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['g'])){
    if(preg_match('%^[0-9]{1,6}$%', stripslashes(trim($_GET['g']))))
    {
        $gVal = $_GET['g'];
    } else {
        $gVal = "0";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['m'])){
  if(preg_match('/^[IMPERIAL | METRIC ]+$/', stripslashes(trim($_GET['m']))))
  {
    $m = $_GET['m'];
  } else {
    $_GET['m'] = "IMPERIAL";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead of trying to concatenate the value yourself. Simply build an array with the values, then "swap out" those that need updating (then call `http_build_query` to put it all together). e.g.

```
// establish initial data:
$params = array(
  's' => $_GET['s'],      // INTERMITTENT
  'm' => $_GET['m'],      // IMPERIAL
  'p' => (int)$_GET['p'], // 1300
  'g' => (int)$_GET['g']  // 1200
);

/* $params validation logic, and maybe fallback values on failures */

// propose a change:
$params['m'] = 'METRIC';

// rebuild:
$query = http_build_query($params); // s=INTERMITTENT&m=METRIC&p=1300&g=1200
```

Then, as long as your form is populated from `$params`, you shouldn't see any duplicated values.

Comment: Despite using the quuery build method, duplicate values are still appending to the URL.

Comment: @AlexSims: where is your submit code? i see hidden inputs, then options assigned to submit buttons. Where does it actually throw that option in to the hidden field and continue?

Comment: I think I have found the problem, it looks like its something to do with the data bindings on my radio buttons. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes I am a total idiot, I forgot to set the binding in my javascript to assign the value :/ sorry for wssting you rtime

Comment: @AlexSims: no worries. ;-)